# Объект проходит сквозь коллайдер

Tags: unity3d

Есть объект с коллайдером и rigidbody, но, стоит сделать коллайдер меньше, объект проваливается сквозь плоскость, которая служит как пол. То есть ситуация такая: я добавил этот объект на сцену и он провалился сквозь plane. Я изменил значение "drag" в rigidbody и все вроде сработало, но объект падает куда медленнее и это не красиво. Я немного поднял его по оси Y и он вроде бы как остановился в нужном месте без изменения "drag". Вопрос: как мне исправить проблему с проваливанием объекта с минимальными размерами коллайдера?